# Spin down after last spark-submit completion (or failure) + xxx time

Tags: apache-spark, timestamp, emr

I'm using Amazon's EMR cluster, but I'm not using the add steps API.  I'd like a way to shutdown the cluster if, for example, it has been idle for 3 days.

If I were to build this, I'd likely just run a history command on the cluster and look for the last `spark-submit` command.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is to check the list of yarn jobs. you can display the running jobs with:

```
yarn application -list
```

-list gives you some more options too, which you might want to explore.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I don't think this actually tells me what I need to know.  If the cluster has been idle for some time, I want to shut it down.  In this case, the `yarn application -list` command will only give me data on what is running... not how long it's been since the last application finished execution.

Comment: Well, you can collect the ids, from yarn application -list, and the query the individual ids with: yarn application -status <applicationid>. That will display the Start-Time (and finish time, once the application is finished)

Comment: In addition, you can also query finished applications wit this command: yarn application -list -appStates FINISHED

Comment: Great!  Thank you for the solution!